How to sync Google Chrome extension settings
I want to be able to sync all my Google Chrome extensions and their settings to a new device. My old device is no longer accessible but I have turned on Sync and set it to Sync everything on my old device. Now that I'm on my new device, I tried to restore everything, yet, even though I was able to get all my history, bookmarks & extensions back, I can't seem to restore my extensions' configurations.
I'm aware that similar questions like this have been asked and that most of them have been resolved. But, most answers seem to hint that the feature is already available in native Chrome. For example, in the thread - Extension or settings in Chrome that syncs settings and extensions?, it is mentioned that:

Google Chrome version 6 now supports this, although at the time of writing you will have to install an unstable development build if you aren't already on the "Dev" channel.

Then here - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/sK_aY44sBIQ, it is also mentioned that:

This was implemented many releases ago. Extensions have a synced data storage location available to them, which lots of extensions use.

Upon further searching I also found the following thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213882/how-to-sync-chrome-extension-options

which has someone mentioning something similar.
However the threads above don't seem to give any guidance on how I could make sure my extensions' configurations are being synched.
Additionally, when I tried looking up the question with Google Gemini, I'm getting the following answer:
Chrome sync currently doesn't sync the individual settings you configure within
extensions. It only syncs the extensions themselves and not their specific settings.
This means you'll need to reconfigure them on each device.

Which seems to contradict the answers given on the threads I have found.
Hence, I'd really appreciate if anyone could enlighten me regarding this.

This quote is fully correct:

This was implemented many releases ago. Extensions have a synced data storage location available to them, which lots of extensions use.

What it means is that extension can use data sync available through an API, but they don't have to. From my own experience, the vast majority of extensions don't support that, unfortunately.
For those that don't, you either need to configure them manually or attempt to copy settings located under each extension's folder in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions, the path is for Windows.
